# Get the total amount charged based on number of months

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, number-formatting, cumulative-sum

I'm having a hard time describing this one thus Googlage isn't helping.

I get charged $0.33/unit/month for warehouse space. Let's say I have 100 units I send to the warehouse. I expect this SKU to sell at 3 units/month. How much would I have paid in total when they all sell out?

The data looks like this:

```
End of Month    Quantity Sold   Total Charge
1               97              $32.01
2               94              $31.02
3               91              $30.03
4               88              $29.04
5               85              $28.05
6               82              $27.06
....
```

The number I want is the sum of each Total Charge cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(UNIQUE(IF(
 SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(100/3)+3, 1, 100, -3)<0, 0, 
 SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(100/3)+3, 1, 100, -3))), {"#", "#"})*{1, 0.33})
```

[image]

so the total is: $566.61

[image]

---

### update:

```
=SUM(INDEX(TEXT(UNIQUE(IF(
 SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(100/3)+3, 1, 100, -3)<0, 0, 
 SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(100/3)+3, 1, 100, -3))), {"#", "#"})*{1, 0.33},,2))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a great start. I can't have all of the values show up though. I just need the SUM value in a cell.

Comment: @AdamBertram answer updated